# React state variable changes unpredictably

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm trying to write a front-end using React for the first time.

I stumbled upon a problem trying to give users the option to order a list of React components and later undo the ordering.

So what I tried to do is save the initial list order in a separate state variable skills_initial. This is done by cloning the skills list. If the ordering gets undone, the skills_initial state variable is used to reset it to the initial order.

```
class Day extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var skills = [];
    var skill;
    var xp;
    for (var i in skill_names) {
        skill = skill_names[i];
        xp = this.props.end[skill] - this.props.start[skill];
        skills.push(<Skill name={skill} xp={xp} key={skill}/>);
    }
    var skills_clone = [];
    for (var k=0; k < skills.length; k++) {
        skills_clone.push(skills[k]);
    }
    this.state = {skills: skills, skills_initial: skills_clone, descend: false, ascend: false};
    this.descend = this.descend.bind(this);
    this.ascend = this.ascend.bind(this);
  }

  descend() {
    document.getElementById('ascend').checked = false;
    if (this.state.descend) {
      document.getElementById('descend').checked = false;
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        skills: prevState.skills_initial,
        descend: false,
        ascend: false
      }));
    } else {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        skills: prevState.skills.sort(
          function(skill1, skill2) {
            return skill2.props.xp - skill1.props.xp;
          }),
        descend: true,
        ascend: false
      }));
    }
  }

  ascend() {
    document.getElementById('descend').checked = false;
    if (this.state.ascend) {
      document.getElementById('ascend').checked = false;
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        skills: prevState.skills_initial,
        ascend: false,
        descend: false,
      }));
    } else {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        skills: prevState.skills.sort(
          function(skill1, skill2) {
            return skill1.props.xp - skill2.props.xp;
          }),
        ascend: true,
        descend: false
      }));
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ol id="skill_list_vertical" style={{listStyleType: "none"}}>
        <input id="descend" type="radio" onClick={this.descend}/>descend
        <input id="ascend" type="radio" onClick={this.ascend}/>ascend
        {this.state.skills}
      </ol>
    );
  }

}

var skill_names = [
"attack",
"defence",
"strength",
"constitution",
"ranged",
"prayer",
"magic",
"cooking",
"woodcutting",
"fletching",
"fishing",
"firemaking",
"crafting",
"smithing",
"mining",
"herblore",
"agility",
"thieving",
"slayer",
"farming",
"runecrafting",
"hunting",
"construction",
"clue_easy",
"clue_medium",
"bounty_rogue",
"bounty_hunter",
"clue_hard",
"LMS",
"clue_elite",
"clue_master"
];
```

So the first two times the radio button is checked, the list is correctly ordered. Only upon trying to undo the ordering the second time, the list remains ordered. In no place the state variable skills_initial is changed unless in the constructor which I thought to be only called once.

Any further advice on my code structure / react habits is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should bind handlers manually (unless you're using property initializers) like this: `this.descend.bind(this)`. Note that for performance purposes it's better to save this to a variable that isn't reset on each render or to use property initializers.

Comment: @NickMcCurdy oh yes, I actually did do the binding in my code but forgot to copy that part while leaving other non related parts out

Comment: Are there any duplicate skill names and do they change over time?

Comment: @NickMcCurdy no, it's just a static list declared in global scope

Comment: I'm running this with `skill_names` set to `['one', 'two', 'three']`. I've toggled the radio button about 10 times and they're still in order. Can you give me your value for that variable?

Comment: https://codepen.io/nickmccurdy/pen/eEJzwg

Comment: @NickMcCurdy thanks for the effort but the codepen doesn't seem to work either for me, not even once. I edited my post to contain the ascend function too, which I left out for simplicity, and the variable skill_names declaration

Comment: @JoshHamet oh my bad, thought I'd leave out the irrelevant parts, the comparing is done on xp aka an integer

Comment: @NickMcCurdy when I replace your array with [1,2,3] it produces exactly the same problem I've been having

Comment: I updated [the same pen](https://codepen.io/nickmccurdy/pen/eEJzwg) with your updated code. I had to remove your imperative radio button toggling (which you should avoid in React anyway) and display values from the state instead. However, I still can't render this without the start and end props. Please click the fork button and provide a link to a pen with the missing code added.

Comment: @NickMcCurdy Thanks for the effort. I updated [the pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzpXeM) and it now shows the problem. Just try toggling the descend radio buttons more than twice.